# how to use "fread" when I don't know the file name(c++)?

Tags: c++, fread

I am using an online judge system and get stuck in I/O problem. How can I use "fread" function to load the test data when I don't know the name of the test file?
Thanks!

Comment: Check the documentation for the online judge system. It should tell you how you get the test data.

Comment: Often the data for an online judge system comes via `stdin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use `stdin` as the stream argument.

```
size_t input_size = fread(buf, sizeof(buf), 1, stdin);
```